# UICollectionViewCell pixel artifacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell, I have few views in its `contentView`.

I have an UIImageView with image (1 pixel colored) and I use it to fill my view.
I also cut the corners like this -

```
self.myBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
self.myBackground.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Color of my view and all collectionViewCells and their contentViews is `[UIColor whiteColor]`

But I am getting weird grey line below it. I am not setting it anywhere and I don't need it.

How can I remove it?

[image: Grey stuff]

Comment: It looks like a shadow. Are you doing anything with shadows?

Comment: Check your 1px image, it may be having this gray/transparency area at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, it is separator. After setting separator view to nil it disappeared.